# Geo Tagged Photos

Tags: iphone, gps, photo, geotagging

Retrieve GPS location from Geo Tagged Photo in iphone.? Can we know the latitude and longitude ogf geo tagged photos in iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably depends on the version of the iPhone you are using.

This thread may be of some help: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11033-getting-gps-data-image-exif.html

Answer (score 0):

See [EXIF](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/)